# Why do buttons shift in a stackview when set to hidden?

Tags: swift

Buttons in a horizontal stackview shift when hidden. Anyway to prevent this? Here is test code.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8d49tki0rhn740/TestIsHidden.zip?dl=0

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, but I ran your dropbox project and the four visible buttons are round. What am I supposed to be seeing happen here?

Comment: Try doing it without StackViews. As you have not set any constraints within the stack for each button with respect to other buttons. Check this for solution without Stackviews.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mxmncqsj1h8v2h7/TestIsHidden%202.zip?dl=0

Comment: The project has six buttons (B1-B6). The fact that they are of circular type is irrelevant. This shows that buttons in a horizontal stack view shift when made hidden. So if I hide button B1, B2 shifts to the left into position where B1 was originally. Here is that exact scenario in a modified zip file.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/9qjpnro7com7zlz/TestIsHidden.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

That's what stack views do. When an arranged subview's `isHidden` property is set to `true`, it removes the view. The stack view also takes care of animating it out. If you don't want them to move, try setting `button.alpha = 0.0` instead.

Comment: I did as you said to no avail.Also, I didn't interpret hidden as moved, more like invisible and not shifting.

[Before pic...no button manipulation][1]

[Button 1 hidden][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaALS.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBDsv.jpg